# Why to include the $C$ in the formula for the distance in hyperbolic geometry?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I'm reading Penrose's: *Road To Reality*. First he gives the Lambert formula and later, he says that *if you want, you can include the $C$* of the Lambert area formula. But It's not clear why I would include that, from his presentation, it seems that the $C$ has to do with scaling but It's not clear what's the role of the scaling in hyperbolic geometry.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Have you gotten to the part of the book in which Penrose explains why he "shall refer to the quantity $C^{-1/2}$ as the *pseudo-radius* of the geometry"?

Comment: @Blue Not yet. I thought I ought to know, mainly because there is an exercise on this page.

Answer (score 3):

$C$ is related to the curvature. If the model being used is the upper half plane, the curvature is $-1$ and $C=1.$ A book that gives full detail on other choices is George Martin, *The Foundations of Geometry and the Non-Euclidean Plane*. The quantity that Martin calls the "distance scale" $k$ is defined in terms of a relationship among horocycles...

It may help to consider trigonometry on the sphere, then vary the radius of the sphere. Very similar, but instead of the angle sum being below $\pi,$ on the sphere it is always above $\pi.$